# Kafka Consumption Issue on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Strange issue here with Kafka in a 2 broker setup with 1 Zookeeper instance, all on AWS. Each broker is in a separate Availability Zone (AZ). The lone Zookeeper instance shares the AZ with one of the brokers.
I'm trying to mock a rolling-restart situation where we want data to flow to Kafka even when a broker is down.

I'm able to see a smooth transition to the broker that shares the AZ with Zookeeper, when the other AZ broker is taken down. However, when I take down the Kafka broker on the AZ that is shared with Zookeeper, the other AZ broker WILL NOT consume data. I see leader allocation happening the way it is supposed to, though. I’m not sure if this is a problem with our setup, Kafka, or Zookeeper.

We have SSL enabled for inter-broker communication, and the producer also uses SSL to talk to Kafka. [Here is the server.properties](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nq0fyboy5ujyns/10.0.3.220.server.properties?dl=0) that's identical on both brokers except for broker-id.
Also [here is our Kafka setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDesn.jpg).

EDIT: I have the same result with a different consumer (used Logstash).

Broker-1 shares AZ with Zookeeper.
Broker-0 is alone on the other AZ.

---

Part-1: Stop Kafka on Broker-0

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.0.1.x:2181 --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 1,0
```

Run consumer on Broker-1.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic test --new-consumer --consumer.config client.ssl
```

Leader is Broker-0. Can consume data on Broker-1
Stop Kafka service on Broker-0.
Can still consume / read data on Broker-1. Leader changes to Broker-1 from Broker-0

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.0.1.x:2181 --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 1
```

---

Part-2: Have both brokers running

Start Kafka on Broker-0

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.0.1.x:2181 --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 1,0
```

---

Part-3: Stop Kafka on Broker-1

Run consumer on Broker-0

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic test --new-consumer --consumer.config client.ssl
```

Leader is Broker-1. Can consume data on Broker-0
Stop Kafka service on Broker-1
CANNOT consume / read data on Broker-0.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.0.1.x:2181 --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0
```

---

Part-4: Have both brokers running

Starting Kafka back up on Broker-1 will resume data consumption instantly. Strangely, messages sent during the apparent “non-consumption” stage also show up once Broker-1 Kafka is back online.

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.0.1.x:2181 --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0,1
```

---

Any insights?

Comment: Just tried the same scenario with THREE zookeepers. Just basically added two zookeepers in the AZ that didn't have any before. Got the same result.

Comment: Also tried to produce to Kafka from both AZs to rule any issues out with subnets.

Answer (score 1):

After a frustratingly long investigation, the problem seems to have stemmed from the fact that Kafka > 0.9 now stores consumer offsets in Kafka and not Zookeeper anymore. There isn't an option to change this to Zookeeper (ala Kafka 0.8) any longer.

Kafka stores consumer offsets in a topic called, well, “__consumer_offsets”. By default, Kafka creates this topic with a replication factor of 0. So, this topic only resides on ONE broker, and ONE broker only. So, when this broker goes down, guess what? Data will still get INTO Kafka but no consumer can read data anymore because it cannot get to the consumer offsets.

So, here’s what I did. I manually changed the replication factor of each of the 50 partitions for this topic one-by-one and ran my tests again. You know the routine from above - kill broker-0, bring it back up, kill broker-1, yada yada. And guess what? Everything worked as expected. Now we know what the issue was!

To have this topic created with  a replication factor of greater than 1, we need to add this property to Kafka conf:

offsets.topic.replication.factor=2

And to have a more reasonable number of partitions for this topic:

offsets.topic.num.partitions=5

However, the awful part is that once this internal topic is created, there is no way to change the replication factor or partition count, unless you tear down the entire infrastructure (Kafka+Zookeeper) and start afresh. Awful! (I hope I'm wrong here)

Now, is this a bug or a feature? I don't know. Either way, it sucks for us.

Comment: Interestingly, it's supposed to be fixed since https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1864 was patched. However, it'll still default to one if you create your cluster with a single broker, and expand afterwards, which maybe is what happened ?

Comment: Yes, @C4stor, you're right. We started out with one broker and added another broker later.